# Boost Serialization : How To Predict The Size Of The Serialized Result?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, structure

I use booost serialization that way :

```
Header H(__Magic, SSP_T_REQUEST, 98, 72, 42, Date(), SSP_C_NONE);
Header Z;

std::cout << H << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

char serial_str[4096];

std::memset(serial_str, 0, 4096);

boost::iostreams::basic_array_sink<char> inserter(serial_str, 4096);
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array_sink<char> > s(inserter);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(s);

oa & H;
s.flush();

std::cout << serial_str << std::endl;

boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> device(serial_str, 4096);
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> > s2(device);
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(s2);

ia >> Z;

std::cout << Z << std::endl;
```

And It works perfectly fine.

Nevertheless, I need to send those packet on a socket. My problem is, how do I know on the other side how many bytes I need to read ? The size of the serialized result is not constant and btw is bigger than sizeof of my struct.

How can I be sure that the data is complete on the other side ? I use circular buffer but with serialisation how to do ?

Thx all

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133621/rule-of-thumb-size-of-boost-archive-in-relation-to-original-serialized-object) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015582/direct-boost-serialization-to-char-array) Q&A seem to give evidence that's it's not really possible to determine the size of a `boost::archive` before the serialization actually took place. But I'm not a `boost` serialization expert at all.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's impossible to predict. It depends (a lot) on the archive format. But with object tracking completely subgraphs might be elided, and with dynamic type information a lot of data could be added.

If you can afford scratch buffers for serialized data, you can serialize to a buffer first, and then send the size (now that you know it) before sending the payload.

There will be overhead for

- object tracking (serializing through pointers/references)
- dynamic polymorphism (serializing through (smart) pointer-to-base)
- versioning (unless you disable it for the types involved)
- archive header (unless disabled)
- code conversion (unless disabled)

Here are some answers that give you more information about these tweak points:

- [Boost C++ Serialization overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459726/boost-c-serialization-overhead/22464553#22464553)
- [Boost Serialization Binary Archive giving incorrect output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556145/boost-serialization-binary-archive-giving-incorrect-output/26568212#26568212)
- [Boost Serialization of vector<char>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950322/boost-serialization-of-vectorchar/27950752#27950752)
- Tune things (boost::archive::no_codecvt, boost::archive::no_header, [disable tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#tracking) etc.)

If all your data is POD, it's easy to predict the size.

### Out of the box

If you share IPC on the same machine, and you're already using circular buffers, consider putting the circular buffer into shared memory.

I have lots of answers (search for `managed_shared_memory` or `managed_mapped_file`) with examples of this.

A concrete example, focusing on a lock-free single-producer/single-consumer scenario is here: [Shared-memory IPC synchronization (lock-free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207546/shared-memory-ipc-synchronization-lock-free/22209595?s=1|0.0000#22209595)

Even if you choose to/need to stream messages (e.g. over the network) you can still employ e.g. [Managed External Buffers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer). Hereby you avoid the need to do *any* serialization even without requiring all data to be POD. (The trick is that internally, `offset_ptr<>` is used instead of raw pointers, making all references relative).

Answer (score -1):

Create your own streaming class and override `xsputn` method.

```
class counter_streambuf : public std::streambuf {
public:
    using std::streambuf::streambuf;

    size_t size() const { return m_size; }

protected:
    std::streamsize xsputn(const char_type* __s, std::streamsize __n) override 
    { this->m_size += __n; return __n; }

private:
    size_t m_size = 0;
};
```

Usage:

```
Header H(__Magic, SSP_T_REQUEST, 98, 72, 42, Date(), SSP_C_NONE);
counter_streambuf csb;
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(csb, boost::archive::no_header);
oa & H;
cout<<"Size: "<<csb.size();
```

Comment: But that gives you the size _after_ serialisation. Unless you hold back the data for transport (as covered much more thoroughly by sehe four years ago) that is too late.